# Linq to Entity - Explanation/Advice on behaviour Where() vs Where().ToList() in foreach loop

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

So the scenario in a nutshell: I have an entity (EF4) that has a foreign key to the primary key in the same entity (hierarchical structure) e.g.

MyEntityId (Primary Key)
ParentMyEntityId (Foreign key to Primary Key)

If I have a MyEntityList `List<MyEntity>` where the EntityState for both is Unchanged:

```
entity 1 - {MyEntityId = 10, ParentMyEntityId = null}
entity 2 - {MyEntityId = 11, ParentMyEntityId = 10}
```

and then I do this:

```
//Initially has 2 items in 'in' clause - iterates once and then exits because the EntityState of the second item has changed to Modified
foreach(MyEntity m in MyEntityList.Where(e => e.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged))
{
     db.DeleteObject(m);
}
```

The first MyEntity is deleted, but the second changes to "Modified" and the foreach doesn't run a second time - I'm guessing due to the foreign key constraint.

However if I do:

```
//Iterates twice, even though the EntityState of the second item has changed to Modified
foreach(MyEntity m in MyEntityList.Where(e => e.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged).ToList())
{
     db.DeleteObject(m);
}
```

Both entities are deleted (which is the desired effect).

Whilst I have a solution, I'm interested in why this happens, I was always under the impression that the iterator "set" that was defined at the start of the foreach loop remained the same, or threw a runtime error if you tried to modify it.

Should I not be using Where? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does you entity `MyEntity` have a custom property `EntityState`? That doesn't look like the `EntityState` stored in the `ObjectStateManager`. How can this property change when you iterate through a list of `MyEntity` objects?

Comment: No it's not a custom property, it's the official EntityState of the entity. I'm able to confirm that it changes by viewing it in the debugger. As I mention in the post, I suspect that because both Entities are attached to the same context, marking the parent entity for deletion results in the context flagging the Entity with the corresponding foreign key as Modified because it's state is dependent on a relationship that is inevitably going to change.

Comment: I see now, `EntityObject` has an `EntityState` property, I forgot that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterator set is defined before the loop runs because you execute `ToList` (if you didn't do this it wouldn't be well defined).

So the iteration source is constant. **But not the object you iterate over.** The object *references* you get are constant but not the objects pointed to by them.

The version without ToList is equivalent to:

```
foreach(MyEntity m in MyEntityList) //always 2 items
{
     //loop body always called two times
     if (e.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged) //2 times
        db.DeleteObject(m); //1 time
}
```

The ToList-version is equivalent to:

```
var copy = MyEntityList.Where(e => e.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged).ToList(); //always 2 items
foreach(MyEntity m in copy)
{
     //loop body always called two times
     db.DeleteObject(m); //2 times
}
```

Comment: the iteration source isn't constant when I use only Where, if I don't use ToList the iteration set is re-evaluated every iteration... I understand that the objects aren't "frozen" in the iteration set. When I use ToList the EntityState still changes to Modified, but the loop still runs twice (which is what I want) whereas, if there is no ToList the Where clause is constantly re-evaluated each iteration and in this case only runs once.

Comment: What you described sounds just about right. A tiny improvement: The evaluation set is not reevaluated every iteration, but each element is evaluated only when it is needed (and at least one is evaluated per loop iteration). Is there some issue left I should elaborate on?

Comment: In the example I give above which I have run in my own app, when the for loop is first reached the Where & Where.ToList both have 2 items to be evaluated in the foreach. However the Where only "actually" iterates once, while the ToList runs twice. I'm sorry but you answer is not clear at all - can you explain the difference between Where & Where.ToList in laymans terms please

Comment: I have added a new code sample, hope that helps. I kind of fail to explain it more clearly. You might want to research the lazy evaluation model of LINQ to objects a little bit to drill down further into this issue.

Comment: I'm sorry you've lost me - you say "The object references you get are constant but not the objects pointed to by them." but clearly this is not the case for the While only version - it points to two items initially and then after one iteration only points to 1 item so clearly this is not constant. I'm after a simple explanation as to why a Where() call responds differently in a foreach loop in comparison to a Where().ToList()

Comment: The iteration source is only constant with ToList. Without it it can change (which is happening). I think the loop code that I added shows the issue exactly. You can step through it in the debugger (you can also step into lambdas).